# First character of span disappears only in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Chrome was the only browser to pick up the :first-letter in my CSS. Solved

Comment: Just guessing... Invalid DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this selector which is hiding it.

```
.old-price:first-letter {
   visibility: hidden; 
}
```

You can find it yourself in the chrome developer toolbar.

Comment: You are right, and I am a tool.